# Unable to solve this error: ImportError

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

```
file0 = open('wiki0.txt','r')
content= file0.readlines()
file1 = open('wiki1.txt','r')
content= file1.readlines()
file2 = open('wiki2.txt','r')
content= file2.readlines()
file3 = open('wiki3.txt','r')
content= file3.readlines()
file4 = open('wiki4.txt','r') 
content= file4.readlines()
doc_complete = [file0, file1, file2, file3, file4]   
import sklearn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, 
max_features=no_features, stop_words='english')
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(doc_complete)
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

from sklearn.decomposition import NMF, LatentDirichletAllocation, 
TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

NUM_TOPICS = 4

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=5, max_df=0.9, 
                           stop_words='english', lowercase=True, 
                         token_pattern='[a-zA-Z\-][a-zA-Z\-]{2,}')
data_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc__complete)

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=NUM_TOPICS, max_iter=10, 
learning_method='online')
lda_Z = lda_model.fit_transform(data_vectorized)
print(lda_Z.shape)
```

I am getting the following error.Can you please help me out with this.

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
>         2 tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, max_features=no_features, stop_words='english')
>         3 tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(doc_complete)
>         4 tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

---

> C:\Users\Vinaya
>   annu\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py
>   in ()
>       131     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
>       132 else:
>   --> 133     from . import __check_build
>       134     from .base import clone
>       135     __check_build  # avoid flakes unused variable error
>
> ImportError: cannot import name __check_build

Comment: Put your traceback in code brackets